# unsupported data type in GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am currently exploring with GORM and have the following struct:

```
type Datasource struct {
    gorm.Model
    Inputs     []string               `gorm: serializer:json`
    Outputs    []string               `gorm: serializer:json`
    Parameters map[string]interface{} `gorm: serializer:json`
}
```

I do initialise my connection with the following func:

```
func ConnectDatabase() {

    database, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to connect to database!")
    }

    err = database.AutoMigrate(&Datasource{})
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    inputs := []string{"input_1", "input_2", "input_3"}
    outputs := []string{"output_1"}
    parameters := map[string]interface{}{"host": "here.it.is", "port": 8090}

    database.Create(&Datasource{Inputs: inputs, Outputs: outputs, Parameters: parameters})

    DB = database
}
```

but get the following error when executing `AutoMigrate`

`[error] unsupported data type: &[]`

Shall I use `datatypes`?

Thanks

Comment: You can use datatypes or write your own types - you have to implement Valuer and Scanner interfaces

Comment: https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html#Scanner-x2F-Valuer

Answer (score 0):

In fact the code above is almost working. `GORM` supports JSON natively but you have to proper annotate your code :-)

```
type Datasource struct {
    gorm.Model
    Inputs     []string               `gorm:"serializer:json"`
    Outputs    []string               `gorm:"serializer:json"`
    Parameters map[string]interface{} `gorm:"serializer:json"`
}
```

See [this link](https://gorm.io/docs/serializer.html#content-inner) for more details.